# Average non-zero elements in a numpy array (2D)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy 2D array, something similar to follows, and I am looking to average the non zero values along the columns.

```
0 0 0 0
0 2 5 0
1 5 8 1
1 5 8 2
0 2 5 0
0 0 0 0
```

Output:

```
[1/2 14/4 26/4 3/2]
```

This question has a solution for numpy matrix, but I have a numpy array. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have an array as `a`, you can divide column sum by nonzero count (`(a != 0).sum(0)` gives count of non zero values for each column):

```
a.sum(0) / (a != 0).sum(0)
# array([1. , 3.5, 6.5, 1.5])
```